# Load Google Map in new window by appending a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append a button to a page that when clicked will display my google map in a new page. I have a button that when clicked either gives an error or gives a blank page.

My code:

```
$('.content--body__wrapper').append('<button id="show-map" />')
$('.content--body__wrapper').append(`<script>
document.getElementById("show-map").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var center = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: center
});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: center,
  map: map,
});
})
</script>`);
$('.content--body__wrapper').append(`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&libraries=drawing" asyncdefer></script>`);
```

Error Code:
[image]

Edit: I took the callback out of the script source and I still don't get a page to load but I do have a lot less errors.

Comment: Where is the `<div>` with id="map"?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Oh ok nice point but you wouldn't call these screenshots verifiable examples when I show code and Output?

Comment: Can you execute a screen shot?  I can't.  A screen shot is useful additional information, but doesn't allow the issue to be reproduced.

Comment: Oh ok thanks with my next code i'll try to get a Jsfiddle with it

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.content--body__wrapper').append('<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" async defer></script>');
```

In this line you say : when the API is loaded run the function called InitMap.
The problem is that this function is not definied in your js.

So remove this callback to use the documentReady event or remove documentReadyListener and create a function name initMap

Comment: So using the DocumentReady eventI would add something like this at the end:                                                                                                          $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });                                                                                                                  My question is where would I insert the API for the page to load here?

Comment: I think you can keep the code you post. Just change $('.content--body__wrapper').append(<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" asyncdefer></script>); to $('.content--body__wrapper').append(<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&libraries=drawing" asyncdefer></script>); without callback=..

Comment: I took out the callback but still a new page doesnt pop up